# Build causal network from stepwise regression analysis , do I need stationarity?

Tags: r, time-series, causality, autoregressive

I am new to time series analysis and struggle a little bit with "causality".
Assume I have the time series Y,X1,X2 and Z.
I want to test if X1 and X2 impact Y and if X1 and X2 are impacted by Z.
I know that there could be no direct causal link between Z and Y .

I try to accomplish this by stepwise regressions.

First, I test if X1 and X2 affect Y and I allow lags (up to p=3) in the model, and trim the model based on GAIC (here using a k of 3, but could be 2 or log(N)) leading to:

`Y~Ylag1+X2+X1lag1`

There is no autocorrelation left in the residuals.

Now I build models for X2 and X1lag, allowing only variables with equal or higher lag and including Z.

For X2 I do not find anything, while X1lag1 is :

`X1lag1 ~ X1lag2+X1lag3+Zlag2`

There is no autocorrelation left in the residuals.

So, there seems to be a relationship of X1 and Z, however I have the following questions:

the p value of Zlag2 is 0.03,

1. do I need to adjust for multiple testing for all p values in the three models leading to my 'causal' network'? then my p value  for Zlag2 is > 0.05
2. Z is the only variable that not passes the ADF test, thus is not stationary. Is this a problem in such an approach?
3. Is doing stepwise regression at all suitable to identify such "causal" networks? I know that some links are not allowed but contemporaneous links could exist, so I would prefer this over e.g., a VAR.

the code can be found below, if data is needed I can share it confidentially over PM.
Thanks a lot.

````
#calculate lags
library(dplyr)
dat<-available_on_req
dat<-dat%>%mutate(Ylag1=lag(Y),Ylag2=lag(Y,2),Ylag3=lag(Y,3),
                  X1lag1=lag(X1),X1lag2=lag(X1,2),X1lag3=lag(X1,3),
                  X2lag1=lag(X2),X2lag2=lag(X2,2),X2lag3=lag(X2,3),
                  Zlag1=lag(Z),Zlag2=lag(Z,2),Zlag3=lag(Z,3))

library(gamlss)
dat<-dat[-c(1:3),]

#causality chain 1 (not including Z)
bnull<-gamlss(Y~1,data=dat,family=TF)
b<-stepGAIC(bnull,scope=list(lower=~1,upper=~(Ylag1+Ylag2+Ylag3+X1+X1lag1+X1lag2+X1lag3+X2+X2lag1+X2lag2+X2lag3)),k=3)


wp(b)
acf(residuals(b))
term.plot(b)
summary(b)
#plot(b)
plot(fitted(b),dat$Y)


# "causality" chain 2 using X2 and X1lag1 (including Z lags >= predictor)

## X2

bnullX2<-gamlss(X2~1,data=dat,family=TF)
bX2<-stepGAIC(bnullX2,scope=list(lower=~1,upper=~(X1+X1lag1+X1lag2+X1lag3+X2lag1+X2lag2+X2lag3+Z+Zlag1+Zlag2+Zlag3)),k=3)
wp(bX2)
acf(residuals(bX2))
#term.plot(bX2)
summary(bX2)
#plot(bX2)
plot(fitted(bX2),dat$X2)


## X1lag1

bnullX1lag1<-gamlss(X1lag1~1,data=dat,family=TF)
bX1lag1<-stepGAIC(bnullX1lag1,scope=list(lower=~1,upper=~(X1lag2+X1lag3+X2lag1+X2lag2+X2lag3+Zlag1+Zlag2+Zlag3)),k=3)
wp(bX1lag1)
acf(residuals(bX1lag1))
term.plot(bX1lag1)
summary(bX1lag1)
#plot(bX1lag1)
plot(fitted(bX1lag1),dat$X1lag1)

# Z plays a role for X1lag1

#get all p values into one table and padjust
table1<-as.data.frame(summary(b))
table1$model<-"b"
table2<-as.data.frame(summary(bX2))
table2$model<-"bX2"
table3<-as.data.frame(summary(bX1lag1))
table3$model<-"bX1lag1"
tableC<-rbind(table1,table2,table3)
# does such an approach require p adjustment and should p_values for intercepts be included in the correction?
tableC$padjust<-p.adjust(tableC$`Pr(>|t|)`,method="BH")
tableC$signi<-tableC$padjust<0.05

# Z is not stationary though, is this a problem here? 
library(tseries)
adf.test(dat$Y)
adf.test(dat$X1)
adf.test(dat$X2)
adf.test(dat$Z)
```
````

Comment: -can I see from my residuals of bX1lag1 if everything is okay regardless of Z not passing the adf test? if I remove a linear trend from Z first it passes the adf test, but it is not significant anymore/not selected in bX1lag1